# C# comboBox.SelectedItem error

Tags: c#

In the comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged when I use

```
        if (comboBox2.SelectedItem == "1")
        {
            MessageBoxEx.Show("Ok1");
        }
        if (comboBox2.SelectedItem == "2")
        {
            MessageBoxEx.Show("Ok2");
        }
        if (comboBox2.SelectedItem == "3")
        {
            MessageBoxEx.Show("Ok3");
        }
        if (comboBox2.SelectedItem == "4")
        {
            MessageBoxEx.Show("Ok4");
        }
```

I get the warning "Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'" and the message boxes do not pop up when that value is clicked. What needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: `comboBox2.SelectedItem.Value.toString()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a ToString() to the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) property

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "1")
```

SelectedItem property is typed as Object and thus you cannot compare against a string without an explict conversion to string.

But I should ask, how do you fill the Items collection? Are the items of string type?
Also do not assume that the SelectedIndexChanged is raised only when there is an item selected.
Add a check before trying to access the SelectedItem property like this

```
if(combobox2.SelectedItem != null)
{
    // Start your checks on the selectedItem
    if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "1")
    {
        MessageBoxEx.Show("Ok1");
    }
    ..... and so on....
}
```

Comment: Using this method I get an exception, and if I were to use try, catch block the functions would not even execute do to the catch; any way to fix that?

Comment: It's a NullReferenceException, and the way I fill the items collection is like this: http://pastie.org/pastes/7758161/text?key=dxr9zcqgebzh7abccmwp0a

Comment: You should not assume that  the SelectedIndexChanged event is raised only when you have an item selected. It there is no item selected the SelectedIndex property is -1

Comment: I'm sorry, What?? I'm not following you; I assumed what..?

Comment: If you get the NullReferenceException it means that your SelectedIndexChanged event is called when there is no element selected in the combobox. Accessing the SelectedItem in this situation leads to the exception. I have added a test on the SelectedItem property before trying to access its value

Answer (score 3):

So let's rewrite this a little because the problem is `SelectedItem` is an `object` and you're comparing a `string`. How about something like this:

```
var val = Convert.ToString(comboBox2.SelectedItem);

switch (val)
{
    case "1":
        break;
    case "2":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

this will also allow you handle the `default` case where you get back an empty string if the `SelectedItem` is `null`. You don't want to *assume* that there will always be a value in `SelectedItem`. Further, **if the `SelectedItem` is `null`, the approach I provided won't throw an exception.** However, this statement `comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

---

OK, so based on your comment, which deviates from the code example, you have two ways of handling OR conditions. The first is leveraging the fall through of the `switch` like this:

```
switch (val)
{
    case "1":
    case "2":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

in that example both `1` and `2` will fall into the same code line. However, if you need even more robust branching you'll have to use `if` statements -but now you won't be getting any warnings and you won't have to worry about a `NullReferenceException` either.

Comment: Okay, so now if I instead want to change the item in the combo box to                                                 eg: if (comboBox2.SelectedItem=="1") || (comboBox2.SelectedItem=="2") How would it be written then?

Comment: Now where do the functions go? I also changed a couple things in above main post because I ended up confusing myself in the way I worded it, and then receiving the answers I've gotten.

Comment: @JohnMcmillan, what do you mean `where do the functions go`? The code I provided goes in place of the example you provided -literally.

Comment: @JohnMcmillan, and in response to this `and the message boxes do not pop up when that value is clicked` -how are you **filling the combo box?** Is it filled with strings or is it data bound to a class?

Comment: @JohnMcmillan, then there shouldn't be a problem with the comparison working with the code I provided -how about the answer to the question about what you mean when you say `where do the functions go`?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `if (comboBox2.SelectedText == "3")`.

Answer (score 1):

Use comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedItem` is an Object. This object contains a `String` property though.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to compare an object to a string ("3"). The compilator warn you because the .toString() might not return what you expect. It warn you so you can do the appropriate action to be sure to have a good comparaison.

In this case, as almost everyone stated, juste simply use *SelectedItem.ToString()*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MessageBox.Show(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());` because `SelectedItem` is an object type datatype. So you have to convert it into `string`